# How to execute Python file

Tags: python, linux, django, filesystems

I am learning Python and DJango and I am relatively nub with Linux. When I create DJango project I have `manage.py` file which I can execute like `./manage.py runserver`. However when I create some Python program by hand it looks like that my Linux trying to execute it using Bash, not Python. So i need to write `python foo.py` instead `./foo.py`. Attributes of both files `manage.py` and `foo.py` are the same (`-rwx--x---`). So my Q is: where is difference and how I can execute python program without specifying `python`? Links to any documentations are very appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed one step, after give the corrects permissions to the file, open your `foo.py` then put this on the first line

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Then you can use ./foo.py

Answer (score 1):

I am just gonna add this for more clarity and to anyone coming across this post who might need an explanation.

[Why do people write #!/usr/bin/env python on the first line of a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script)

explains why you should it is used.

Comment: I needed an explanation and I already found it when @levi explain to me the direction of search. In any case thanks and +1

Answer (score -2):

Save your python code file somewhere, using "Save" or "Save as" in your editor. Lets call it 'first.py' in some folder, like "pyscripts" that you make on your Desktop. Open a prompt (a Windows 'cmd' shell that is a text interface into the computer): start > run > "cmd".

Comment: OP OS is linux not window.

Comment: I am not such nub to saving anything to the folder on the Windows desktop *~<;o) Yes you are really missed `linux` in the question tags (I does not downvote your answer if any, thanks for try and have fun)